# read text from text editor and place it in a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently working on a feature that is live feature. How it works is that when user types in a wysiwyg editor, all that text will be read as the user is typing and place that text in a div element. The problem is that when I change the styles such make it bold of text then that text is still copied as a normal text i.e. without styles. How can I read the text from that editor including its styles and place it exactly as it is appeared in texteditor?

I am currently using [plugin](http://jqueryte.com/) for wysisyg editor.

Below is my code which reads text and place it in div but the text is normal.

```
$('body').on('keyup', '.jqte_editor', function () {
    $('.element').text($(this).html());
});
```

**Update**

I already tried `.html()` but this put html tags around that particular text. I want the text to be literally visible as bold if it is made bold in editor. I don't want to see those tags.

Comment: "Update": which is what my answer and all the others should be doing.

Comment: Working example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the other answers have posted, you need to use the `.html();` method. To show you, I have made a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mfL5e/

```
$('.jqte_editor').jqte();

$('body').on('keyup', '.jqte_editor', function () {
    $('.element').html($(this).html());
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the text, not the html of the element

```
$('.element').text($(this).html());
```

needs to be

```
$('.element').html($(this).html());
```

Comment: .html() will place html tags in there. e.g. if I have text bold then in div it will appear like <b>text</b>. I want this to be literally as bold.

Comment: REALLY? lol Did you Try it? If you are still getting the tags, you did not change the text()

Answer (score 0):

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) sets text contents, use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/), as:

```
$('body').on('keyup', '.jqte_editor', function () {
    $('.element').html($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the literal html out of it instead of text:

for example if you are using jquery something like this:

```
$('.example').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

use .html instead of .text

Below is the code with modification

```
$('body').on('keyup', '.jqte_editor', function () {
    $('.element').html($(this).html());
});
```